# AspNetCore.SignalR 2.1 and CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm migrating our SignalR-Service to the new AspNetCore.SignalR (2.1 preview) and now I get problems with CORS. I will never access the service from the same origin, so I need to disable CORS in general.

I have the folowing CORS policy

```
services.AddCors(
            options => options.AddPolicy("AllowCors",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                })
        );
```

*(My WebApi-Controller calls from a different origin are working fine with these policy)*

With the old preview package of SignalR for AspNetCore (AspNetCore.SignalR.Server) I don't got any problems but now, my test client got some http-405 which seems like an issue with CORS.

Is there maybe a extra CORS configuration for SignalR, or do I need to allow something else?

**Edit**:
I created a fresh/clean sample project without any special middleware to check If the error happens here and it does.

**Sample WebApplication | startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebApplication1.HUBs;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(
                options => options.AddPolicy("AllowCors",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                    })
            );
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSignalR(options =>
            {
            });
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("AllowCors");
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<TestHub>("/test");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Winforms Application**

```
        private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:63771/test")
            .WithConsoleLogger()
            .WithTransport(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.TransportType.WebSockets)
            .Build();
        connection.StartAsync();
    }
```

**Sample Winforms Application ConsoleOutput**

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Client.HttpConnection[8]
   01/10/2018 15:25:45: Failed to start connection. Error getting negotiation response from 'http://localhost:63771/test'.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
   bei System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Client.HttpConnection.<Negotiate>d__42.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Are you passing in the value "AllowCors" to the `app.UseCors("AllowCors");` in the `Configure` method in *Startup*? That should be all you need.

Comment: Do you have this in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` of `Startup.cs`: app.UseCors("AllowCors");

Comment: I should be more clear; the line of code in my comment isn't *all* you need. You need that, as well as the code you already have in the `ConfigureServices` method. They work together.

Comment: Yes I already use the policy I've created. My WebApi-Controller are already accepting calls from X-Origins, so I can be sure the policy itself works correctly (for the REST-Controller) but not for the SignalR connections.

Comment: @slxSlashi have you ever fixed it?

Comment: This is in the code listing in the OPs question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to move `app.UseSignalR()` on top of `app.UseMvc()` like this

```
app.UseCors("AllowCors");
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<TestHub>("/test");
    });
app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: I spent a day trying to figure this out.  Can you explain why this needs to be done this way?  I'm guessing it's because the UseMvc method might rely on the SignalR route to be "registered" already

Comment: @MichaelJ.Heier  I hate seeing unanswered questions so: UseMvc is configured with the default route when called that way, so it needs to be the last route in the collection to allow the other routes to take precedence when mapping requests ... In this case the exception is caused by MVC handling something SignalR should be handling.

Comment: This answer is deprecated, now.  The recommended way is to do this mapping in endpoints: endpoints.MapHub<TestHub>("/test");

Answer (score 16):

This didn't work for me and a subtly different version did -

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
    .AllowCredentials()
  );

  app.UseSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub"); });
  app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: After like 5 hours of searching for the answer, including all the other answers on this page, this option worked for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ian Grainger, thanks! I had the same configuration, save one item.  By adding SetIsOriginAllowed, in your example, made my client web app connect to my api app (hub)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I use reactjs for clientside.
Changing the version from using `"@aspnet/signalr-client"` into `"@aspnet/signalr"` solved my problem

Comment: Worked for me on Angular 5 app.

Answer (score 2):

If you're migrating your project to asp.net core version 3.x, you can upgrade [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code) from the `Configure` method like this:

```
app.UseCors("AllowCors");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapHub<TestHub>("/test");
});
```

`app.UseMvc` and `app.UseSignalR` will be replaced with `app.UseEndpoints`. `app.UseSignalR` also cannot be used anymore because:

> This method is obsolete and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: I also need to use OData and can't use MapODataServiceRoute in UseEndpoints

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade your package to `@aspnet/signalr` when upgrading to preview1:

> NOTE: Previous previews of the SignalR client library for JavaScript
>   were named @aspnet/signalr-client. This has been deprecated as of
>   Preview 1.

[source: Github readme](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/dev/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

The client-package and the server-package were not in the exact subversion state.
It was 2.1-preview3210 and 2.1-preview3209 (example numbers).

The server-package is published to the nuget feed frequently but the client-package (npm) not. So I cloned the latest git repo by myself and build the libs and it works.

You will not have the problem anymore, the client-package is now up-to-date.