# SignalR Core call function when connection is established

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

When my client successfully connects to the hub, I want the client to immediately join a group. I have a method in my hub to do that, I just need an event handler for when the connection is established, just like

```
connection.start().done(
    function () {
        connection.invoke('JoinGroup', 'GroupName');
    });
```

in SignalR for plain ASP.Net.

Can I do that or do I have to set a timer to do it after x seconds after the `start();` call was made?

Edit:

I found out I can do

```
connection.start(
    function (){
            connection.invoke('JoinGroup', 'GroupName');
    }
);
```

but it tells me that it `Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.`

what do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SignalR is notoriously difficult due to version mismatches etc.

Please see the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

In it, there's a section that specifies how to start (and wait for connection to be established):

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();
connection.start().then(() => {
  //try some stuff here :)
})
.catch(function (err) {
  //failed to connect
  return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

The javascript client uses promises that have to be resolved/rejected before you can use it.
The other option is to wrap inside async method and await the call (not sure if this will work correctly). Such as:

```
await connection.start();
//connection should be started now. beware of exceptions though
```

Comment: I tried `await connection.start()` but it told me that's only for async functions. I'll try the `then`. thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, it has to be inside an async function(){} :-).
No problem. Good luck!

Comment: It's still saying `Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.` but it does recieve method calls sent to the client group it's supposed to join. I guess that's good enough.

Comment: Check out in the hub, there are two methods called OnConnected and OnDisconnected that you can override from inherited hub for troubleshooting.

Comment: So, you seem experienced with SignalR. It's weird, using the `.then()` approach I still get the `Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.` message, but it works, as mentioned before. Notice this is with cross origin. I have another client in a different group that is connected from the hub's machine, and it doesn't get that problem, with basically exactly the same code. Do you think it's just a timing issue that the second client connects faster or do you think it's some kind of configuration issue?

Comment: "Experience is simply the name we give our mistakes" - Oscar Wilde. :-)
So, I suspect that the client that's failing to connect you get some error before it stating failed to negotiate (or something to that effect)

The answer is to enable something called CORS.

Basic example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185985/aspnetcore-signalr-2-1-and-cors

I recommend you look into the CORS stuff for ASP core and setup a policy only whitelisting your domain.

Comment: I have CORS enabled and it works fine - it's just that I get that message but apparently it works nevertheless. I guess I'll have to give names to the clients. client 1 - cross origin, recieves error message, still joins group and reacts on signals. client 2 - connecting from same machine (or docker container to be exact), doesn't get error message with fundamentally same code, reacts to signals. I'm just confused why client 1 gets the error message but still works. Neat quote btw ;)