# SignalR not workin on IIS ( CORS issue ERROR 405 )

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, cors, signalr

I developed and Angular AspNetCore application.
In my development environment everything works fine.
I can make a hub connection with signalR and use it without any issues.
When I publish to IIS(10.0) however, I get the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/chart/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:8034' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

On the server side in Startup.cs my configure services method contains this piece of code:

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowCredentials()
                                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    );
            });
```

and in the Configure method defines the signalr route

```cs
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chart");
            });
```

and adds the cors policy

```cs
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

I tried:

- Changing to different ports
- Chaning my Hub connection url to the port I deploy my IIS server on (8034)

This results in this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8034/chart?id=vzjCtGG-Glo_8i-1j7oFDA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value
```

- Enabling Https
- Changing AllowAllOrigin to WithOrigin("http://localhost:8034", ...)
- Adding HttpProtocols to web.config

```xml
      <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

## Locally it works as a charm:

**General**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/chart/negotiate
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

** Response Headers**

```
Content-Length: 252
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 31 Oct 2019 01:51:05 GMT
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcQmFzZW1lbnRMYW5BcHBcQmFzZW1lbnRMYW5BcHBcY2hhcnRcbmVnb3RpYXRl?=
```

**Request Headers**

```
Provisional headers are shown
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Referer: http://localhost:5000/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

## When publishing to IIS on port 8034 it doesn't work.

**General:**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/chart/negotiate
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response headers:**

```
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 31 Oct 2019 01:28:35 GMT
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcQmFzZW1lbnRMYW5BcHBcQmFzZW1lbnRMYW5BcHBcY2hhcnRcbmVnb3RpYXRl?=
```

**Request headers:**

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8034
Referer: http://localhost:8034/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
```

This are my Launch settings:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ChartApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why I get this 405 exception on my published environment.
I allow requests from all origins, so I would expect the response header to contain "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = "true".

What am I missing?

Comment: The server the request is being sent to isn’t properly configured to handle OPTIONS requests. That configuration is something separate than your CORS config. Try using Postman or curl or some other non-browser tool send an OPTIONS request to that server, and you’ll get the same 405 Method Not Allowed error. The answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185985/aspnetcore-signalr-2-1-and-cors may or may not help.